# Call WebAPI method from MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an `MVC4 WebAPI` project and have a controller `FileController` that has this Get method in it:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
       return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "File Name Not Specified");

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    var stream = fileService.GetFileStream(id);
    if (stream == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File Not Found");
    }

    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = id;
    return response;            
}
```

In the browser going to `localhost:9586/File/myfile.mp3`it dispatches the file correctly as an attachment and you can save it. If it is an audio file, you can stream it from the `HTML5` audio tag.

Now, I need to call this `WebAPI` method from an `MVC4` web app, basically wrapping it. Here it comes:

```
public HttpResponseMessage DispatchFile(string id)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8493/");

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/File/"+id).Result;

    return response;
}
```

Going to `localhost:8493/File/DispatchFile/my.mp3` returns:

> StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Pragma: no-cache Connection: Close Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2013 15:33:23 GMT Server: ASP.NET Server: Development Server: Server/10.0.0.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 Content-Length: 13889 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=horse.ogg Content-Type: application/octet-stream Expires: -1 }

So it looks like the Content is indeed StreamContent, but it doesn't return it as a saveable file. Now the question is, how to mirror the behavior when calling the API directly? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: I don`t got It! Do you want stream or provide a download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the use of HttpClient.Result is not the correct approach here. I think you may need to use the 'Content' property and then call ReadAsStreamAsync to get a handle on the file stream that is returned by your WebAPI method. At that point, you should be able to just write this stream to the response stream, allowing the file to be downloaded / audio to be streamed via HTML5.

See here for an example of using HttpClient to get a file (the link shows how to handle large files, but I believe the approach used there is what you will need to do):

http://developer.greenbutton.com/downloading-large-files-with-the-net-httpclient/